# An elusive jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

I've tried for hours to write a selector for the following code.
I would appreciate some help!

Below is part of the html for my own drop-down menu.

Q: How do I select 'a#projects' if I have click, say 'a#residential' ? 
(I wish to change the color of the parent link, in this case 'a#projects'.)

I have multiple submenus, so it is not practical to just select '#projects'.

```
 <div id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a id="projects" class="main_menu" href="#">01 </a><span class="hover">projects</span>
     <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a id="residential" href="">residential</a></li>
      <li><a id="commercial" href="">commercial</a></li>
      <li><a id="master_planning" href="">master planning</a></li>
      <li><a id="modular" href="">modular</a></li>
      <li><a id="interiors" href="">interiors</a></li>
     </ul> <!-- end of projects submenu -->                 
        </li><!-- end of projects menu-->
    </div><!-- end nav -->
```

Thanks for your help. I have really benefited from this website thus far.

Comment: So, you want to select the link in the parent `li`? What have ytou tried? Have you had a look at the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 1):

Here is general way:

```
$('.submenu a').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest('ul').closest('li').children('a').addClass('selected');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EcySu/)